# This code executed perfectly for 2 years, now returning errors. Debug shows the breakpoint as below. ( If Len(cel) > 0 Then)

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub TranslateAllCells()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim translateFrom As String
    Dim translateTo As String
    Dim getParam As String, trans As String, objHTTP As Object, URL As String
    Dim cel As Range
    translateFrom = Range("L4").Value
    translateTo = Range("L5").Value
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    Set rng = Application.Range(Cells(11, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
      With cel
        If Len(cel) > 0 Then
          getParam = cel.Value
          URL = "https://translate.google.pl/m?hl=" & translateFrom & "&sl=" & translateFrom & "&tl=" & translateTo & "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & getParam
          objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
          objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
          objHTTP.send ("")
          If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, "div dir=""ltr""") > 0 Then
            trans = RegexExecute(objHTTP.responseText, "div[^""]*?""ltr"".*?""t0"".*?>(.+?)</div>")
            cel.Value = Clean(trans)
          Else
            cel.Value = CVErr(xlErrValue)
          End If
        End If
      End With
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Has anything changed with the file you run this on?

Comment: What's the error? You don't need `with`.

Comment: You have an error value in your `cel`?

Comment: If the cell contains an error, you won't be able to use its value. Test `If IsError(cel)` before continuing with your code.

Comment: What is the Error that is thrown? Please update with that otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: When i run the code i get an error in each cell: #VALUE!

Comment: Apologies if im not using the site correctly, and thanks to all that took the time to comment.

Comment: A popup appears with run time error '13'. When i debug it brings me to this line:  If Len(cel) > 0 Then

Comment: Please provide the error code you are getting as well as any additional details help use to understand it.